# How to show side by side merged two images into an ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm creating an ImageView programmatically in my activity. And I want to add two images side by side from internal storage into the ImageView. How can I do it?

Comment: Why didn't you make two ImageView? Maybe it's more easy, and you will haven't to use image manipulation.

Comment: I can't because I want to add multiple touch zoom fature to ImageView. When I do it, images has separate zoom features.

Comment: You could put both `ImageView` in a layout and zoom the layout?

Comment: @user802421 how can I zoom the Layout? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I have been using this approach for scaling/zooming multiple components. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13369768/802421