# Disable clipping of a scaled view?

Tags: android, view, drawing

I'm creating a game that will have a map (an image) with some features (other images) on top.  So far I'm using a subclassed View and draw everything in an `onDraw` method, but I'd like to keep the images as `ImageView`-s, so that I can animate them (fade-in when creating, move, etc) with Android built-in methods.

So I have the following structure:

```
FrameLayout (match_parent)
    AbsoluteLayout (match_parent)
        map: ImageView
        feature1: ImageView
        ...
```

Since the map is larger than a viewport, I want to apply a scale to it.  While it's possible to apply the same scale to each individual image, I'd like to keep the coordinates of all the feature images relative to a canonical size of the map and apply the master scale in a single place, namely AbsoluteLayout.  The problem is that when I set `scaleX` and `scaleY`, the child images are clipped: the only part showing is that which would be shown if the scale wasn't applied.

This is what it looks like without applied scale:

```
  device screen
,--------------.
| @@@@@@@@@@@@ | @@@@@
| @........... | .....
| @........... | imaginary map continues
| @........... | .....
| @...big map. | .....
| @........... | .....
| @........... | .....
| @........... | .....
| @........... | .....
| @........... | .....
`--------------'
  @...........   .....
  @...........   .....
```

When I apply scale, I see this: the same part of map is visible, but scaled.

```
,--------------.
| @@@@         |
| @...         |
| @...         |
| @...         |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
`--------------'
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
,--------------.
| @@@@@@@@@@@@ |
| @..........@ |
| @..scaled..@ |
| @...map....@ |
| @..........@ |
| @..........@ |
| @@@@@@@@@@@@ |
|              |
|              |
|              |
`--------------'
```

Ie apply scale to the containing layout, but make it draw the "overflow", not clip it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The original title of this question is "Don't clip a scaled view", because I want to disable clipping of a scaled view (i.e. don't clip a scaled view).  The new title doesn't make sense for this question.

Comment: Have you played around with [ImageView's ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) at all? Setting those would likely achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23651842/832474) has what I need: just set `setClipChildren(false)` on the outer container (the FrameLayout).